# Is there a better way to reset form fields after getting a success dispatch from thunk in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I am making a Post API call in thunk and dispatching a boolean success key for success and an error message when getting error.

I now want to clear the form data for success and show the error message for an error.

For that, in `componentDidUpdate()` I am checking

```
componentDidUpdate(){
const {success, errorMsg} = this.props;
if ( success )
    this.setState(defaultState);
else if(errorMsg!=='')
    //show error
}
```

Now I have to dispatch an action to reset both success and error in my redux store otherwise it will run into infinite render cycle.

But I think this is a bit complicated for achieving such a simple task because if I call the API in component itself on button handler then it is way easier.

So I wanted to know if there is a better way to achieve this task using thunk?

Comment: Our team usually pass a callback as a parameter in dispached action. After that you can use that callback to pass sucess/error back or trigger proper transition

Answer (score 0):

You could handle it like this:

**Redux form state**

```
state = {
  loading: false,
  formState: {...},
  error: null
}
```

**Action creators**

```
const submitStart = () => {
  return({
    type: "SUBMIT_START"
  });
};

const submitSuccess = () => {
  return({
    type: "SUBMIT_SUCCESS"
  });
};

const submitFailure = (error) => {
  return({
    type: "SUBMIT_FAILURE",
    payload: { error }
  });
};
```

**Action thunk**

```
export const submitForm = () => {
  return async (dispatch,getState) => {
  
    dispatch(submitStart());

    try {
      await callApiToSubmitForm();
      dispatch(submitSuccess());
    }
    catch(err) {
      dispatch(submitFailure(err.msg));
    }

  };
};
```

**Reducer**

```
function reducer(state,action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
 
    case "SUBMIT_START" : {
      return({
        ...state,
        loading: true
      }); 
    }

    case "SUBMIT_SUCCESS" : {
      return({
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        formState: {...}   // RESET FORM STATE HERE
      });
    }

    case "SUBMIT_FAILURE" : {
      return({
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        error: action.payload.error
      });
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: But my 'formState' is in the component not in redux store.
I have to reset it in component

Comment: @MadhurBansal And what part is in Redux state?

Comment: Redux state has the response of the api i.e. a boolean key for if response was success or failure and error message key for response error.